# Close tab after redirecting to a new tab in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am trying to close a tab using JavaScript on Firefox. I went through a few older questions posted here on Stackoverflow and I understand that Firefox doesn't allow a tab to be closed using JavaScript unless the tab has been opened from JavaScript itself.

However, I could open a blank tab in place of the existing tab using
`window.open('about:blank','_self','');`.

My question is since the blank tab has been opened through JavaScript, why can't I close it using `window.close();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is since the blank tab has been opened through JavaScript

The tab **wasn't** opened with JS. A `window.open` call just used the name of an existing tab so the document was loaded there instead of opening a new window.

Comment: thanks for this.It makes perfect sense.Is there any work around possible,to close the tab in `Firefox `

Comment: I hope not. That sort of security problem should be mostly patched these days.